# jQuery dropdown not working when appended

Tags: jquery, append, jquery-chosen

Im appending a form & it contains `select` - Im using jQuery select plugin [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

Like expected, jQuery Chosen dropdown doesn't work (because it's appended & jQuery doesn't attach automatically, right?).

---

**I've tried:**

- `jQuery('#color').chosen().trigger("chosen:updated");` but it seems
  that it's only useful if you add more `options` dynamically, there doesn't seems to be built-in Chosen functionality for that kind of situation. **Result:** does absolutely nothing.
- Added `Chosen jQuery code` under `jQuery append function`. **Result:** it attaches Chosen to `select` 2 times, 1st is "original" which doesn't work & second one works (not very useful if there's 2 same rendered dropdowns & one doesn't work)..

  ```
   jQuery('.add-color').click(function() {
        colorGroup = jQuery('.color-item').html();
        jQuery('#color').append('<div class="color-item row">'+colorGroup+'</div>');

            jQuery('select').chosen({
                disable_search: false,
                disable_search_threshold: 5,
                width: '100%'
             });
   });
  ```
- Also tried to combine `Chosen jQuery code` with `on()` - it didn't work out & generated errors, I might have done something wrong. **Result:** errors!

  ```
   // Tried something like this
   jQuery(document).on('chosen', 'select', function({
       disable_search: false,
       disable_search_threshold: 10,
       width: '100%'
   });

   // Like you can see, it doesn't work out very well & Im not that 
   // good yet to combine these two - function works differently than Chosen
  ```

---

**Question:** How to make Chosen work if it's appended or dynamically loaded?

---

jQuery append functon:

```
jQuery('.add-color').click(function() {
    colorGroup = jQuery('.color-item').html();
    jQuery('#color').append('<div class="color-item row">'+colorGroup+'</div>');
});
```

Chosen jQuery on page load:

```
jQuery('select').chosen({
   disable_search: false,
   disable_search_threshold: 5,
   width: '100%'
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="color">
        <div class="color-item row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                <select name="color-type[]">
                    <option value=""><?php _e('Color', 'tt'); ?></option>
                    <option value="1"><?php _e('Red', 'tt'); ?></option>
                    <option value="2"><?php _e('Blue', 'tt'); ?></option>
                    <option value="3"><?php _e('Black', 'tt'); ?></option>
                    <option value="4"><?php _e('White', 'tt'); ?></option>
                    <option value="5"><?php _e('Yellow', 'tt'); ?></option>
                    <option value="6"><?php _e('Pink', 'tt'); ?></option>
                    <option value="7"><?php _e('Green', 'tt'); ?></option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" name="color-name[]" id="color-name" class="form-control"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <input type="number" name="color-code[]" id="color-code" class="form-control"/>
            </div>         
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix col-sm-12">
            <a class="add-color btn"><?php _e( 'Add Color','tt' ); ?></a>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First bind the document of every click

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.add-color',function() {
```